# USB tries to install onto itself (dual-boot with Win10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, windows-10

I'm just trying to dual-boot my XPS and have followed the instructions by Dell [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/audhs1/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I've gotten as far as booting into Ubuntu on the USB drive but when I go to install it's saying there's not enough space on the drive - because it's only looking at the USB...

I've created the blank partition via Windows 10 (as per the instructions) but aren't having any luck getting Ubuntu to see it. I've configured all the BIOS settings Dell goes over, just cannot crack it. I also did a `sudo fdisk -l` and only the drive and a couple other 512 byte drives come up.

Any help would be muchly appreciated! I've read a bit about the drive type, it's set to RAID - would that have something to do with it?

Comment: you created a partition or freespace (unallocated)?

Comment: @ravery yes I did this and it's unallocated

Comment: There could be several problems, and several of them are covered in a previous answer. See the link in the next (automatically generated) comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: yes, RAID is probably the issue, But changing the setting to AHCI will require the AHCI drivers to be installed in Windows. Reinstalling Windows in AHCI mode is probably the easiest but there are many tutorials about how to convert a Windows install from RAID to AHCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detection of `NVME` drive on your Dell laptop, please choose `SATA Operation` from `"RAID"` to `"AHCI"` in the BIOS settings. For more information, you can check following link [Unable to detect PCIe M.2 NVMe SSD - Dell XPS 13 (2016)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204629)

Comment: Thanks @arryph but I've read a lot of horror stories about not being able to boot back into Windows after doing this... Is this the only solution?

Comment: Boot into windows os, run from terminal `msconfig` change boot settings to _safeboot_ (just tick the safeboot option in boot settings tab), reboot to check if your windows os is booting into safeboot by default. Reboot, go to bios settings, change sata operation to `AHCI` and reboot, after booting into _safeboot_ windows, you can just disable _safeboot_ by running msconfig and un-tick _safeboot_ as it was before. you will be able to boot into windows with new `AHCI` drivers.