# No options to try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows

I'm trying to dual boot my Dell XPS 15 7590 running Windows 10 Pro with Ubuntu 18.04. After booting the live USB with *try Ubuntu without installing* or *install Ubuntu* I cannot actually install the OS.

I'm using a 8 GB USB stick, but I cannot select the 128 GB partition I created before. I could only select the language and keyboard layout before this error message shows up:

> You need at least 8.6 GB of free space to install Ubuntu. This computer only has 8.0 GB.

Any idea what I could have done wrong?

Comment: This link might help.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/978269/usb-tries-to-install-onto-itself-dual-boot-with-win10?rq=1

Comment: Aah, yes indeed. The SATA setting in the boot menu had to be set to AHCI. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB tries to install onto itself (dual-boot with Win10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978269/usb-tries-to-install-onto-itself-dual-boot-with-win10)

Comment: Think there is a line in the link that windows won't be happy.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Windows was indeed not booting up after changing to ACHI, I followed this link to get around it: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci